# Alternate syntax for "while True" loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm still relatively new to Python and have been using statements like the following:

```
flag = False
while flag == False:
    # Do something here that might set the flag to True,
    flag = True
```

However this could be written like so:

```
while not flag:
    # Do something...
    flag = True 
while flag is False:
    # Do something...
    flag = True
```

With a further (preferred?) way of writing this type of loop:

```
while True:
    # Do something and if wanting wanting to break out of loop,
    break
```

The first three methods are more explicit, so why are they (or one of them) not preferred over the fourth method? Are there any differences between the first three ways of writing the "while flag == False"?

Comment: if you want to make your intention clear in the condition of the while loop, I'd create a `didnt_break_yet = lambda: True` and use it like `while didnt_break_yet(): # Do something`. That way you make it clear that the loop is *not intended to run infinitly long*

Comment: You use whatever works in the context of your code, if there are multiple options you choose whatever your personal preference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are technically different.

**Example 1**

Say you have a function call that doesn't return anything meaningful, as follows:

```
def fun(x=None):
    return x
```

Now, for your while loops, all of which will be defined as follows:

```
def while1():
   flag = False
   while flag == False:
      flag = fun(None)

def while2():
   flag = False
   while flag is False:
      flag = fun(None)

def while3():
   flag = False
   while not flag:
      flag = fun(None)
```

In this case, only `while1` and `while2` will terminate. Since `bool(None)` evaluates to `False`, `while3` will continue infinitely, but since `None != False` and `None is not False`, both `while1` and `while2` will terminate.

Now, this gets more interesting with more complicated examples.

**Example 2**

```
def fun(x):
    return x
```

Now, for each of our loops, we're going to change `flag = fun()` to `flag = fun(0)`.

In this case, `while1` and `while3` terminate, while `while2` continues indefinitely. This is because `bool(0) == False`, and `0 == False`, but `0 is not False`.

**Example 3 -- Mutables**

Now, this gets a lot more complicated with mutables, which is why the explicit versus implicit depends situation to situation. Mutables are any object that can be modified, and include dicts, lists. Immutable objects are anything that cannot be modified, such as tuples, ints, floats, strs.

Say I have the following:

```
a = []
b = []
```

In this case, `bool(a) == False`, and `a == b`, but `a is not b`. In short, there is no, simple, steadfast rule for how to check falsey or truthey values.

However, there are general rules.

**General Rules**

**Checking None vs. Other**
If you accept any value other than None, check `x is None`.

**Checking mutables**
Never use `x is b`, since mutables can have different IDs, unless if you explicitly want to check to an object with the same ID (`id(x) == id(b)`.
Typically, check `not x` or `x == b`

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
>>> not a
True
```

**Checking strs, floats and ints**
For strs, floats and ints, always check `x == b` and not `x is b`. This is since for short strs, floats, ints, the results can be true if `x == b`, but for more complicated cases, your code will stop working.

For example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a is 1
True
>>> a = 10000000
>>> a is 10000000
False
```

**Checking booleans**

For booleans, you can do any of the above, but `not x` is preferable to `x == b` or `x is b`.

**Finally... While Loops**

If you can, always convert a while loop to a for loop. This isn't always possible, but say you want to do a simple case:

```
x = 0
while x < 10:
    print(x)
    x -= 1
```

This can be converted to:

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x)
```

The reason for using for loops rather than while loops is if some error occurs in your code, while loops can lead to an indefinite loop and crash your program, while a for loop will always exit.

Comment: This is an incredibly helpful answer, thanks! I think for any of my current  applications I can continue to use any of the methods as `flag` is only ever set as `True` or `False`, but basically using `while True` avoids any of these issues arising, correct?

Comment: @Lotte, yes. `while True` is a great statement until a condition is set. If you can, convert your while loop to a for loop, but if you need to convolute your code to do so, while loops exist for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a preference really. A while-loop will continue to execute the code block as long as the boolean expression specified remains True.

flag == True, not Flag, i < 6 or evaluate to boolean expressions. If you just say while True like in your example, you will just enter an infinite loop. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

While the first three are more explicit, the last one is more readable and clear. This I would say makes it the greater option above the other three. There won't be any searching for the initialization of some variable for the loop. With that said, all of the methods are perfectly acceptable and you should use the one that is more comfortable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `while True:` syntax is fine for simple logic. Once you start breaking out of the loop from multiple locations or need to track if the loop was successful then it gets to be messy.

Also, if the while condition is named correctly then it sort of documents why you are looping.

```
while not end_of_file:
   ..read read read..
```

Avoiding the `break` statement in loop, IMHO, makes code more readable. Just like avoid multiple `return` statements in a function.

Comment: I'd like to ask what the reason for avoiding multiple `return` statements is? Is it only for clarity? I may be guilty of this.

Comment: @Lotte, for clarity and also for more practical reason of debugging code. Nice to have once place where all code exits so you can figure out the return values.